# Let $S$ be any set. Prove that $S\setminus\{0\}$ is countable if and only if $S$ is countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory

bit stuck on this question.

> Let $S$ be any set. Prove that $S\setminus\{0\}$ is countable if and only if $S$ is countable.

This question seems a bit intuitive to answer, however I'm not quite sure how to go about *proving* the statement. It makes sense but I don't know where to start.

I'm thinking that if $S$ is countable then that must mean that there is a bijection function mapping all elements one to one, but don't really know where to go from here.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  since $S$ is countable, there is a bijection between $S$ and the naturals.  Then $S \setminus \{0\}$ is either $S$ or $S$ less one element.

Comment: So in the case that S is is still itself after removing {0}, then we can assume its countable just from the statement that S is countable. But if S has one element less, then the bijection function used to map Naturals -> S would move up one? I dont know how to word it :P

Comment: You should already have shown there is a bijection between the naturals and the naturals less one element.  You can make a chain from the naturals to naturals less one to $S$ less one.  This is a common method of proof, showing a chain of bijections.  It lets you reuse results you already have.

Answer (score 0):

If $f:N\to S$ is a bijection where $N=\{0,1,2,...\}$. Then restricting on complement of  $f^{-1}(\{0\})$, the restricted function is just the bijection. The other case can be similarly done by enlarging $N$ to $\{-1,0,1,...\}$ and define $f(-1)=0$, and the extended $f$ is a bijection from $\{-1,0,1,...\}$ onto $S$.